# How to output whole information when using group_by and summarize

Tags: r

My data has continent, country and dif(number).I am now trying to find the maximum of dif by each continent, and following is my code. How can I get the countries name at the same time?

```
dt_dif %>%
  group_by(continent)%>%
  summarize(max_dif = max(dif))
```

Comment: Try to make this a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)—we can't run your code without your data, and can't see any of what you're working with or what this code gets you. You want the row with the maximum value per continent?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

We can use `slice` to return the row of the dataset with the `max` value of 'dif'

```
library(dplyr)
dt_dif %>%
    group_by(continent) %>%
    slice(which.max(dif))
```

---

Or using `filter`

```
dt_dif %>%
    group_by(continent) %>%
    filter(dif == max(dif))
```